# Build MEX from C/C++ in Matlab R2017b in Catalina 10.15.2 with Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: xcode, matlab, macos-catalina

Getting the following error in Matlab R2017b:

```
Error using mex
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSFont._fFlags
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.9.4.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.9.4.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
xcrun: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
xcrun: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

I've downloaded the older version of Xcode 9.4 that supposed to be compatible with Matlab R2017.b and set the path to it:

```
> xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer
```

any suggestions would be grand!